# could not get Environment variable in staging server in rails 3 and capistrano 2.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, capistrano, digital-ocean

I am working on rails 3 application . I use capistran 2 for deploying purpose on digital ocean.

Now, I want to store the clients gmail username and password. 
I do not want to store it into the code as it is sensitive information.

I want to store it to the server environment variable .

so I make env. variable by following command

```
export NEW_VAR="Testing export"
```

I checked it by following command and its saved as env. variable

```
echo $NEW_VAR
```

Now I want to access it in my rails application at environment folder in staging.rb and production.rb

I try to use the dotenv gem but it gives me difficulty in getting the env. variable as I am using capistrano 2.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Figaro gem. Its pretty easy to setup. https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro